# QWebView doesn't show JPEG images on a clean XP machine

Tags: jpeg, qwebview

I use QWebView in my application. On my machine where Qt 4.7.2 and visual studio 2008 are installed QWebView displays images without any problems. But when I tried to run it on a clean XP SP2 it didn't.

Found some posts about the same problem:
http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-17469.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4...ent-on-windows

As it was suggested there, I copied imageformats folder to the directory where my app is located. So the file/folder structure is "MyAppFolder\imageformats" and "MyAppFolder\myapp.exe". But still have no JPEG images displayed. By the way, Qt sample facybrowser has the same problem.

Any ideas?