# Convertion decimal sql type to .net float type

Tags: c#, sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have decimal (18,2) data in sql and I set float the property of class in .net side. When I select the object .net returns an error like this:

```
The 'DiscountRate' property on 'Product' could not be set to a 'Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Single'.
```

Do you have suggestion?

Comment: It would help to post the table structure and your class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .NET code double or decimal type for decimal(18, 2).

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for a cross reference from SQL to .NET types.

Now if you decimal column can be null make sure you use the nullable decimal or

```
public decimal? DiscountRate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need to either change your property in your .NET class to a decimal type or do an explicit conversion to a float when setting it. Which you use is really dependant on your code though using a decimal type seems more correct without any further context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Decimal Type`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx

You can read `Specifying Parameter Data Types section`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should change the property to `decimal`. It makes conversion easier and protects you from rounding errors that come with `float` or `double`.

Here's an extensive discussion of the issue: [decimal vs. double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/when-setting-a-forms-opacity-should-i-use-a-decimal-or-double)