# How to trim/replace a char '\' or '"' from a string?

Tags: c#

I need to use a string for path for a file but sometimes there are forbidden characters in this string and I must replace them. For example, my string _title is `rumbaton jonathan \"racko\" contreras`.

Well I should replace the chars `\` and `"`.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
_title.Replace(@"/", "");
_title.Replace(@"\", "");
_title.Replace(@"*", "");
_title.Replace(@"?", "");
_title.Replace(@"<", "");
_title.Replace(@">", "");
_title.Replace(@"|", "");
```

Comment: Which language? Java? C? VB?

Comment: Strings are not mutable in .NET.

Comment: Also, you never replace `"\""`...

Comment: Always describe "it doesn't work"

Comment: @user1306322: Why is what?

Comment: @leppie "Why do you never replace `"\""`?", obviously

Comment: @user1306322, because he never does that in his code. He is only replacing the `\` character.

Comment: @user1306322: `@"\"` is just removing `\\`

Comment: A useful answer based on `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393722/60761)

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I will try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could try this (probably terribly inefficient) method:

```
string inputString = @"File ~!@#$%^&*()_+|`1234567890-=\[];',./{}:""<>? name";
var badchars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
foreach (var c in badchars)
    inputString = inputString.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
```

The result will be:

```
File ~!@#$%^&()_+`1234567890-=[];',.{} name
```

But feel free to add more chars to the `badchars` before running the foreach loop on them.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I did (answer upper ;) )

Answer (score 4):

Since strings are immutable, the `Replace` method returns a new string, it doesn't modify the instance you are calling it on. So try this:

```
_title = _title
    .Replace(@"/", "")
    .Replace(@"""", "")
    .Replace(@"*", "")
    .Replace(@"?", "")
    .Replace(@"<", "")
    .Replace(@">", "")
    .Replace(@"|", "");
```

Also if you want to replace `"` make sure you have properly escaped it.

Comment: Small bug, see my comment ;p

Comment: Oh yes indeed. Good catch.

Comment: I will try it too ! Thank you for your patience !

Answer (score 2):

Try regex

```
string illegal = "\"M\"\\a/ry/ h**ad:>> a\\/:*?\"| li*tt|le|| la\"mb.?";
string regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));
illegal = r.Replace(illegal, "");
```

Before: "M"\a/ry/ h**ad:>> a/:*?"| li*tt|le|| la"mb.?
After: Mary had a little lamb.

Also another answer from same post is much cleaner

```
private static string CleanFileName(string fileName)
{
    return Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(fileName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty));
}
```

from [How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames)

Comment: Do look at the 2nd answer, much cleaner.

Comment: @HenkHolterman there are no first, second or any order of answers, they are sorted by the number of votes and that is subject to change

Comment: @user1306322 There is if you compare the times of each answer and look for the oldest > youngest

Comment: @DGibbs very soon it will be difficult to do so, since the minutes won't be visible, and I doubt anybody would go through the trouble of comparing the posting dates visually. Unless they *really* want to find out what happened here.

Comment: @user1306322 At the time he posted his comment, it was quite easy to determine the 2nd post by time due to minutes being visible. Now, not so much. As they age I believe the minutes are shown again along with hrs/day/month/year etc...

Comment: @DGibbs oh, you're right! This oldest question has exact dates near all posted answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4/1306322

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/fk49wtc1.aspx:

> Returns a string that is equivalent to the current string except that all instances of oldValue are replaced with newValue.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method to do the exact operation that you want and with much cleaner code.

#### The method

```
public static string Delete(this string target, string samples) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(target) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(samples))
        return target;
    var tar = target.ToCharArray();
    const char deletechar = '♣'; //a char that most likely never to be used in the input
    for (var i = 0; i < tar.Length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < samples.Length; j++) {
            if (tar[i] == samples[j]) {
                tar[i] = deletechar;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return tar.ConvertToString().Replace(deletechar.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), string.Empty);
}
```

#### Sample

```
var input = "rumbaton jonathan \"racko\" contreras";
var cleaned = input.Delete("\"\\/*?><|");
```

Will result in:

> rumbaton jonathan racko contreras

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! I've solved my issue thanks to all your indications. This is my correction :

```
string newFileName = _artist + " - " + _title;
char[] invalidFileChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
char[] invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
foreach (char invalidChar in invalidFileChars)
{
        newFileName = newFileName.Replace(invalidChar.ToString(), string.Empty);
}
foreach (char invalidChar in invalidPathChars)
{
        newFilePath = newFilePath.Replace(invalidChar.ToString(), string.Empty);
}
```

Thank you so musch everybody :)