# ASP.NET web API HTTP Delete 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I already worked with web API and had a lot of problems like posting multiple parameters. I upgraded to WebApi2 to use routing attributes and now have problems like:

`"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."`

I spent all day searching Stack Overflow and the web to solve the problem:

- Removed `webdav`
- In `http protocol` allow all `get,put,post,delete`
- Added the `[HTTPDelete]` attribute
- Added `name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*."`
  `verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
  type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
  preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"`
- Searched Google for the necessary help [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=web%20api%202%20The%20requested%20resource%20does%20not%20support%20http%20method%20%27DELETE%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=nQ2kUrrpFcaGrgesnYDIAg#q=web%20api%202%20%20Method%20Not%20Allowed%20DELETE&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&start=0)

Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: Your title needs be more descriptive

Comment: The problem with giving us a search query (in number 5) is, are we meant to believe that you've accessed all 1 million results that that query returns (at least for me, today)? If not, how does it help us to help you?

Comment: I tried four items mentioned above from search result

Comment: So no answer? Amazing, out of nothing comes a big issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When setting a form's opacity should I use a decimal or double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/when-setting-a-forms-opacity-should-i-use-a-decimal-or-double)

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem. Adding the below code to your web.config should fix the problem under the `system.webserver` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
```

Comment: --> didi it for me:  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too, was very odd because the issue occured after the app was working fine on the dev server for weeks. An unrelated update to a different page somehow caused this error, but this fixed it!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, because my controller was like this:

```cs
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string Id)
{
     ....
}
```

And on the client I used the send the ID as request body:

```
var url = '/api/upload';
var data = JSON.stringify({ 'Id': id }); // <-- In the body
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: data, // <-- in the body
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

When I changed the client to use it as URL parameter instead it worked:

```
var url = '/api/upload/' + id; // <- In the URL
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'DELETE',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: I think you need all that its in the above answer plus make the request correctly

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript code for the DELETE verb must be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    **url: "/api/SomeController/" + id,**
    type: "DELETE",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, statusText) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, error) {
        alert(error);
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Do NOT use something like this,

```
...
data: {id:id}
...
```

as when you are using the POST method.

Comment: Pavel Kharibin, you saved my day. Thanks for answere