# How to run SSH on port 443 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, port

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and try to run SSH on port 443. I updated /etc/ssh/ssh_config to
HTML Code:

```
Port 22
Port 443
```

After I restart SSH I can access SSH on port 22, but on 443 it's still not working. Any idea? I haven't installed Apache or set firewall. I just have base installation.

I found similar problem on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7...-over-port-443 But on my log /var/log/auth is nothing and if i run
`lsof -i :443` nothing happens.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is config for ssh client, instead you should look for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to change server port.