# Issue with Navigation Controller logic

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I've started to code my first app and got first challenge.
I need menu logic as on the picture below:

[image]

So, what is correct way to realize it?

1. Main menu should be separate View Controller with Segue to Navigation Controller?

or

2. Navigation controller is initial controller for the app and main menu is a root view for navigation controller? I've tried to do like this but I don't have an idea how to hide top bar from main menu (I don't need it on main menu view)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: __point 2.__ can do the job for you.

Comment: You could use a `UITabBarController` and let it act as the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When setting a form's opacity should I use a decimal or double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/when-setting-a-forms-opacity-should-i-use-a-decimal-or-double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 2. You should make navigation controller an initial controller of the app, and main menu should be a root view controller of the navigation controller.

To hide navigation bar use [setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden:animated:)

One of the option is to place this hide/show functionality in viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear methods of menu view controller as described here [iPhone hide Navigation Bar only on first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page)

In case 1 you will have to implement yourself back functionality and back-forward animation which will require a lot of code.