# How to capture a string from the parameters of a url using regex expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a function that will display urls visited by users e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78/of/103/uk/ask

I want to use a regex expression with javascript to capture a specific parameter of the url and replace it with placeholder text. Taking the example above;

When https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845w98439/uk/ask is matched, replace the '/78/of/103/uk/' part with '/task/of/total/country/'. The code below I have doesn't seem to work. Can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

JS:

```
const url_change = [
  {expression: '/^/78/of/103/uk//i', value: '/task/of/total/country/'}
];

const urlParam = url_change.reduce(function(result, item) {
        return element.classList.contains(item.expression) ? item.value : result;
    }, '');

return urlParam(
  toChange ? toChange.value : getElementText(element)
);
```

Comment: you have to escape all slashes in the regexp `/^\/bla\/bleh etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as follow:

```js
var str = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78/of/103/uk/ask";
const url_change = [
  {expression: /\/78\/of\/103\/uk\//i, value: '/task/of/total/country/'}
];
// console.log(url_change[0].expression.test(str));
var result = str.replace(url_change[0].expression,url_change[0].value);
console.log(result);
```

Sign `/` is special character (announces the end of Regex expression), it needs a mark `\` lead to become a `/` in url, for Regex expression!